# jQuery ui tabs not rendering at all

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to set up a tabs panel in my website. The problem is, it's not rendering. Below is a link to the page and the relevant html:
http://develop.emotion-software.nl/admin/pages/edit/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
})
</script>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="POST">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Slug</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Page</a></li>
           </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                Titel: <input type="text" name="title" /><br />
                Slug: <input type="text" name="slug" /><br />
                Model: <input type="text" name="model" /><br />
                View: <input type="text" name="view" /><br />
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                    Titel: <input type="text" name="title" /><br />
                    Beschrijving: <input type="text" name="description" /><br />
                    Keywords: <input type="text" name="keywords" /><br />
                    Tekst:<br />
                    <textarea name="text" cols="80" rows="15" class="ckeditor">abjioo</textarea><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I created a try-out file with minimal HTML. In that file the tabspanel does work. :http://develop.emotion-software.nl/tab.html

There's probably an error somewhere. I just can't find it.

Comment: no error in the console?

Comment: It has become even weirder. I managed to get the tabs up (some other javascript was interfering). But not the homepage is being rendered inside the tab. But the HTML is not being reloaded as the source is clean.

Comment: You'd need to post the updated code. BTW, you don't need the inner `$(function(){}` call (just the `$('#tabs').tabs()`), it is the same as `$(document).ready()`. In effect you are calling it twice here.